# Why is -[NSPasteboard writeObjects:] returning NO for an array of NSURL objects?

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nsurl, nspasteboard

I have an NSArrayController that I'm using to provide data to an IKImageBrowserView. I want to support drag and drop from the IKImageBrowserView to other applications. Here's the relevant method from my code:

```
- (NSUInteger) imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *) aBrowser writeItemsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *) itemIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard{
    NSArray *items = [[resultsArrayController arrangedObjects] objectsAtIndexes:itemIndexes];
    if(![pasteboard writeObjects:items]){
        return 0;
    }
    return [items count];
}
```

My app is new so I'm targeting 10.6+ and according to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPasteboard), "On Mac OS X v10.6 and later, use writeObjects: to write URLs directly to the pasteboard instead."

I've verified that the objects that I am attempting to write are indeed NSURL objects, so I'm not sure where the process is breaking down or how to further troubleshoot the problem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you cleared the pasteboard yet? You need to do that, and thereby become the pasteboard's owner, before you can write objects to the pasteboard.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That was it exactly. Adding that to my toolbar of technicalities to remember. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that your `pasteboard` variable is not nil?

Comment: Hadn't before and it was a good thought, but alas, no dice. It's not nil. :( Related: Why can't Cocoa have whiny nils like Ruby?

Comment: @jxpx777 regarding whiny nils, I agree completely. I find it amazing that Cocoa will happily let me perform selectors on nil objects without complaining. So much time wasted.

Answer (score -1):

Are the objects that are to be sent to -[NSPasteboard writeObjects:] supposed to be NSPasteboadItems? You can set their string value to the absoluteString of the NSURL and write an array of NSPasteboadItems.

Comment: See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/writeObjects: . Any objects that conform to the `NSPasteboardWriting` protocol are acceptable, and NSURL objects (when AppKit is present) do conform to this protocol.